# Is it good to load all javascripts under asset javascripts

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I wonder what's practice is better to load Javascripts in Rails app.

Because every page will load all the js files under asset folder.

But most of coffescripts are only apply on their own controller.

So to `require_tree .` seems a bad idea, here.

So I need to include corresponding coffee script for each view ?

It also seems a bad idea, and easily to cause maintain problem.

Any idea ? Thanks

[image]

### Application.js

`//= require_tree .`

Comment: It's good practice if you are using `turbolinks` because you only load the library once... Also, at production, assets are compiled into one dirty file each for css and javascript. If you are not using turbolinks, then you need to change the headers in your layout file. Is this your case?

Answer (score 1):

By default Rails handles assets at the controller level and will automatically include the appropriate assets as long as they are in the right file, which corresponds to a controller. In this case it works correctly with the `//= require_tree .` directive.

If you prefer, you can also include controller specific assets manually in layouts or views like so: `<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>` or `<%= stylesheet_link_tag
params[:controller] %>`. In this case your `require` directives should not have `//= require_tree .`. Remember that you will have to specify any files not in your `require` directive for pre-compilation in production.

For more see the Rails documentation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html, under '2.1 Controller Specific Assets'.